# How to free up space on RPi 2 root card?

Tags: files, raspbian, download, deluge

I just set up my RPi 2 running Debian (few months old) as a Torrent box with [this tutorial](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-always-on-bittorrent-box/58487). I created a directory on /media for the USB Thumb stick to automount but I must have made a mistake on that step. As the torrent seemed to work fine I left it running over the night but this morning I saw that there was some error. My card had filled up.

Since then I have mounted the USB properly and rectified the automount command. But I can't seem to find the downloaded files to clear up my card. I can't even upgrade the OS.

```
root@(none):~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          7.2G  7.2G     0 100% /
/dev/root       7.2G  7.2G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        214M     0  214M   0% /dev
tmpfs            44M  388K   44M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            88M     0   88M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   20M   37M  35% /boot
/dev/sda1        58G  8.6G   50G  15% /media/64GB-Sandisk-AutoMount
tmpfs            88M  4.0K   88M   1% /tmp
```

Any suggestions on where the downloaded files might be? I need to clear up the space to make the system run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The files are probable "under" /media/64GB-Sandisk-AutoMount ie you have mounted the USB thumb stick over it
Try this:

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt
```

You can then look in /mnt/media/64GB-Sandisk-AutoMount for the files.
If that doesn't work run this:

```
sudo du -sh /mnt/*
```

This will tell you how much space each subdirectory is using and it is likely your files are somewhere under the one using the most space.

When you have finished run:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: Per your suggestion, I unplugged the thumb stick and ran the find command from the other answer and found the old files on the mount folder and have successfully deleted them. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

In your `df` you can clearly see the filesystems that are filled.

Both `rootfs` and `/dev/root` are maxed out:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          7.2G  7.2G     0 100% /
/dev/root       7.2G  7.2G     0 100% /
```

The other file systems seem fine.

To find the files that you downloaded (obviously you need to know the filename or a partial snippet of it), use the find command from the root of each file system:

```
find /* -type f -name "<filename>"
```